# RadRails + Ruby Installed on Virtual Machine (Ubuntu)

Tags: ruby, ide, customization, radrails

I have installed Aptana RadRails IDE on my computer under Windows. Also I have Ubuntu guest OS where installed ruby environment. RadRails ask me for ruby installation at start. But I don't want duplicate installation of ruby and gems on Windows. Is there a possibility to use my guest OS ruby installation in RadRails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible.
You have to install RadRails on VM or ruby and gems on Windows.
I prefer first because of fatal performance of rails on Windows.